# Get standard application for txt files (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

In my application I want to open a text file, which has no .txt extension. Is there any way to get the standard application for .txt files in .NET (C#)? Sure I could use "notepad", but there might be some people (like me), who prefer another (their standard) editor.

---

Edit:

The registry key "[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT]\txtfile\shell\open\command" references notepad, but that's not my standard app for txt files. How do I get the my current standard app for .txt?

Comment: It's actually under textfile, non txtfile.  See @Ben Voigt's answer for the correct way to find it.

Comment: @mellamokb it's txtfile, no 'e', on my PC. textfile with an 'e' is write.exe not notepad, so was probably rtf etc. on machines without Word

Comment: it varies.. see Ben Voigt's answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @Rup: It varies by computer.  On my computer it is *txtfile*, on iDog's it is not (apparently).

Comment: on my computer it's "Notepad++_file"

Comment: @Ben sure, I just thought textfile-with-an-e was unlikely and so mella's attempted correction was wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The absolute best option is to use [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/ShellExecuteEx.html), passing the `SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME` flag, to open this file as if it were a `".txt"`.  This is the only method that will support things like DDE-based and drag-and-drop-based file opening mechanisms.

But if you want to do it yourself (e.g. running with partial trust and can't p/invoke `ShellExecuteEx`), here's how:

There's another level of indirection.  You first have to lookup

> HKCR\.txt

Read the default value out of that key, call it *txtkey*.

Then check

> HKCR\ *txtkey* \shell\open\command

There's also a function to do this for you: [AssocQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773471.aspx)

Comment: @iDog: But wait, there's more.

Comment: @Ben: AssocQueryString sounds very good. Is there still more??

Comment: @iDog: The "more" was `ShellExecuteEx`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you'll have to access it via P/Invoke, but the cleanest way is probably to create a temporary file with the extension you care about, and call [`FindExecutable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776419.aspx) for the temporary file. You can then use that executable to open the file you care about.

Comment: If p/invoke is an option, there's `AssocQueryString(ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE)`

Answer (score 1):

My code that include some checks to prevent from some common errors... Hope it helps :-)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace HQ.Util.Unmanaged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Usage:  string executablePath = FileAssociation.GetExecFileAssociatedToExtension(pathExtension, "open");
    /// </summary>
    public static class FileAssociation
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ext"></param>
        /// <param name="verb"></param>
        /// <returns>Return null if not found</returns>
        public static string GetExecFileAssociatedToExtension(string ext, string verb = null)
        {
            if (ext[0] != '.')
            {
                ext = "." + ext;
            }

            string executablePath = FileExtentionInfo(AssocStr.Executable, ext, verb); // Will only work for 'open' verb
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(executablePath))
            {
                executablePath = FileExtentionInfo(AssocStr.Command, ext, verb); // required to find command of any other verb than 'open'

                // Extract only the path
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(executablePath) && executablePath.Length > 1) 
                {
                    if (executablePath[0] == '"')
                    {
                        executablePath = executablePath.Split('\"')[1];
                    }
                    else if (executablePath[0] == '\'')
                    {
                        executablePath = executablePath.Split('\'')[1];
                    }
                }
            }

            // Ensure to not return the default OpenWith.exe associated executable in Windows 8 or higher
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(executablePath) && File.Exists(executablePath) &&
                !executablePath.ToLower().EndsWith(".dll"))
            {
                if (executablePath.ToLower().EndsWith("openwith.exe"))
                {
                    return null; // 'OpenWith.exe' is th windows 8 or higher default for unknown extensions. I don't want to have it as associted file
                }
                return executablePath;
            }
            return executablePath;
        }

        [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint AssocQueryString(AssocF flags, AssocStr str, string pszAssoc, string pszExtra, [Out] StringBuilder pszOut, [In][Out] ref uint pcchOut);

        private static string FileExtentionInfo(AssocStr assocStr, string doctype, string verb)
        {
            uint pcchOut = 0;
            AssocQueryString(AssocF.Verify, assocStr, doctype, verb, null, ref pcchOut);

            Debug.Assert(pcchOut != 0);
            if (pcchOut == 0)
            {
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder pszOut = new StringBuilder((int)pcchOut);
            AssocQueryString(AssocF.Verify, assocStr, doctype, verb, pszOut, ref pcchOut);
            return pszOut.ToString();
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum AssocF
        {
            Init_NoRemapCLSID = 0x1,
            Init_ByExeName = 0x2,
            Open_ByExeName = 0x2,
            Init_DefaultToStar = 0x4,
            Init_DefaultToFolder = 0x8,
            NoUserSettings = 0x10,
            NoTruncate = 0x20,
            Verify = 0x40,
            RemapRunDll = 0x80,
            NoFixUps = 0x100,
            IgnoreBaseClass = 0x200
        }

        public enum AssocStr
        {
            Command = 1,
            Executable,
            FriendlyDocName,
            FriendlyAppName,
            NoOpen,
            ShellNewValue,
            DDECommand,
            DDEIfExec,
            DDEApplication,
            DDETopic
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to open the .txt file directly.

```
Process.Start("MyFile.txt");
```

It should automatically open with the preferred text editor.

**Edit:**

Whoops, didn't see it doesn't have .txt extensions.  Probably have to check in the registry for the preferred editor?

**Edit:**

It's here on my computer (Windows 7): HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\textfile\shell\open\command

Comment: See the question: "which has no .txt extension"

Comment: Thanks, but that file hasn't a .txt extension. Imagine a .bat file. In that case "Process.Start" would start that batch file.

Comment: -.- closed, but that duplicate doesn't solve my problem.. cause under that registry entry I only find "%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1".. and that's not my standard app for .txt

Comment: @iDog: Agreed.  I changed mine to wordpad, and the registry key doesn't change.

Comment: wordpad was my second choice, but wordpad doesn't highlight xml tags (nor has it any highlighting feature). The people, who are going to use my app, have notepad++ installed (or most of them). So I need to know their standard app for .txt. :-)

Comment: @iDog, mellamokb: I can't remember exactly when it was introduced, but I'm pretty sure that at least Vista and Win7 allow user-specific associations, which would be stored somewhere under HKCU instead of HKCR. Perhaps your changed association was set there instead?

Comment: @Michael: HKCR is a virtual hive overlaying HKCU\Software\Classes on top of HKLM\Software\Classes.

Comment: @Ben: Indeed it is; my mistake. In that case, I don't have any bright ideas here.

Comment: @Michael: Found it here on my comp (Win 7): HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\textfile\shell\open\command

Comment: @mellamokb: Part of that path is a variable (see my answer) which varies.